# If i click on a link could it contain a virus inside iphone + IOS 14.4

Tags: virus, ios, windows-10, iphone

I was searching for some articles on google using my iphone 11, IOS version 14.4 >> and i find a link inside google search result >> then i click on the link which is from a trusted site >> but after that while the page was loading i got redirected to this link:-

```
https://vpndefence2plus.com/2/10/vml/index.html?clickcost=0&browser_name=Mobile%20Safari&language=en-US&clickid=ba1e22tvcib16a6519&campaign=747&device_model=iPhone&os_name=iOS&os_version=14.3&country_code=JO&isp=Jordan%20Data%20Communications%20Company%20LLC&zoneid=3754661&lander=87&bin=3&domain=yourkarazim.com&caid=13&uclick=2tvc3vb7pm&uclickhash=2tvc3vb7pm-2tvcib16a6-sydz-2t3z-bzfn-vc7v-vc8r-3a5046
```

and it ask me to download a program to be able to view a video >> so i close the browser.. **but could my iPhone got a virus or has been hacked since i got redirected?** now I did the same google search but now from my windows 10 PC and when i click on the same google link and i got the correct article without been redirect.. **so not sure what is going on? why i were only redirected if i click on the link using my iPhone?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can visiting a malicious website infect an iOS or Android device?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76680/can-visiting-a-malicious-website-infect-an-ios-or-android-device)

Comment: @Martheen yes it is useful.. so seems just visiting a website can cause an attack.. so how i can check if my iphone is infected and fix this?

Comment: @test the top voted answer says no.

Comment: Can, yes. Probable? No. The answer in that link point out such security hole is usually patched very quickly. Still a problem for Android where updates may never comes (at least for the OS level, browsers will still be promptly updated) but you're using the latest iOS and doesn't install anything (not that it will be easy to install in the first place), so the risk is really small

Comment: @Martheen yes the link asked me to install something.. but i did not install it.. instead i close it... so is removing safari from my mobile device and re-install it a valid approach to follow? so i can eliminate the possibility that my safari web browser was affected?

Comment: You can't remove Safari on iOS. It's fine, nothing that cached by a domain is visible to other domain in Safari, so there's nothing affecting any other site. Feel free to clear the browser cache if you want